# Did I find a (little) bug (empty space in the Nautilus context menu)?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gnome-shell, context-menu

I know that it's just a tiny graphic problem but do you also get a white line (or extra padding) after the last entry in the context menu?

[image]

Comment: Do not know about Unity, but in Xubuntu this (little) bug does not exist.

Comment: I have bigger fish to fry and wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: This isn't the place for bug reports. Even if it were, you'd have to provide a lot more info.

Comment: Exactly which release of Ubuntu?

Comment: I suspect it's 19.04 because of "Preferiti" which I'm guessing is "Starred" and that is related to Tracker being on by default in 19.04. Of course, OP, as a perfectionist, should have provided that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite possibly a bug. Using **Ubuntu 19.04**, I see the extra space in one context menu but not in another:

**Extra space at the bottom of this context menu**

[image: Extra space at the bottom]

**No extra space at the bottom of this context menu**

[image: No extra space at the bottom]

If you want to file a bug, there are things you could do first to make sure the developers' task is made easier.

- Verify if the issue exists in another distribution you know uses the latest vanilla GNOME such as Fedora 30. If the issue appears there as well, you'd be better off approaching [upstream](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME) and not the Ubuntu team [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net).
- See if the problem goes away using the built-in *Adwaita* theme. In this specific case, I've used *Adwaita-Dark* and so it doesn't appear to be a theming issue caused by using a "non-standard" theme.
- If you see the issue only when **not** using *Adwaita*, you should get in touch with the developer of the concerned theme. The reason for doing so is detailed in [Please don’t theme our apps](https://stopthemingmy.app/).

Comment: Issue is also present with Adwaita indeed. It is good nevertheless to point to the possibility of a custom theme causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/1996

This bug seems to be triggered by the "paste into folder" feature.

If you copy a file/folder to your clipboard, then there's no empty space.